# How to fix apis google code on my website?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

On this website https://webprominds.com/, I think the apis google error is making it slow?

I have already tried to upgrade the website with https but the problem still occurs.

```
plusone.js:37 GET https://apis.google.com/u/0/se/0/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=1&size=medium&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwebprominds.com&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwebprominds.com%2Fkim-kardashian-hollywood-hack-no-survey%2F&gsrc=3p&ic=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.y5hhWjOdu80.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNsKzxWFhezE2KkFP7auTmVDBiNEQ%2Fm%3D__features__ 404 ()
Wc @ plusone.js:37
yd @ plusone.js:52
ud @ plusone.js:46
Ka @ plusone.js:53
(anonymous) @ plusone.js:54
La @ plusone.js:9
Ma @ plusone.js:9
(anonymous) @ plusone.js:54
ub @ plusone.js:15
M @ plusone.js:16
(anonymous) @ plusone.js:18
vb @ plusone.js:18
C.load @ plusone.js:18
(anonymous) @ plusone.js:62
```

404 error

Answer (score 0):

So this is probably a bit late to solve your problem but mighhelp others if they find it as I did.

The reason for your 404 on the

```
url https://apis.google.com/u/0/se/0/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=....
```

is because Google have closed down Google Plus - it is from a 'follow us on Google+' button.

From Google:

"Google+ is only available for G Suite accounts through work or school. Consumer accounts (typically ending in @gmail.com) were shut down on April 2nd, 2019."